# Google Maps radarSearch by name odd behavior

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Experiencing strange results when using radarSearch and the name parameter...

I have a long list of stores stored in a db, I'm trying to display markers for each store that is found. It seems like when I use the full list, it doesn't return anything, even stores that I know exist. If I include a shorter list it then seems to work, but then some markers are not including store "marker" details, store name, address, phone number in the infoWindow.

Originally in my request I was just using all the stores in the name paramater, but that didn't work at all, so I thought I would then perform a search for each store, which is kind of working... but again when the list is long it doesn't return anything, not sure if the script eventually just stops after so many request that are not found or what.

I've included a fiddle and have put comments in the script part of the google maps, and included the full list of stores.

I'm not sure if this is a google maps limitation, or a specific store name that throws off the results or what is going on.

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bowenac/k7xfbwsg/16/

```
function performSearch() {
  markers = [];
  jQuery('#store_list').empty();

  //Full List of Stores
  //var storeList = 'Vitamin Shoppe|GNC|Fred Meyer|Kroger|King Sooper|Ralphs|Sprouts|Hi-Health|Harmons|Fresh Thyme|HEB|United|Rite Aid|Meijer|Harris Teeter|Wakefern|Publix|Winn-Dixie|BiLo|Walgreens|Walmart|Kmart|CVS|Longs Drugs|Hannaford|Stop & Shop|Giant Food|Weis Mkt|PURITANS PRIDE|BJs WHOLESALE CLUB PACKS|Viatamin World';

    //Only works when not using full list I know these work for 98444
  var storeList = 'GNC|Rite Aid|Fred Meyer|Walgreens|Walmart|Kmart|CVS';
  var splitStr = storeList.split('|');
  for (var i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
    //console.log(splitStr[i]);
    var request = {
      bounds: map.getBounds(),
      name: splitStr[i]
    };
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
  }
}
```

Anyone have any idea on what could be happening here?

Comment: Where do you see it say that something like `'GNC|Rite Aid|Fred Meyer|Walgreens|Walmart|Kmart|CVS'` should work?

Comment: Says you can here, this is for nearbySearch, but I've seen example with radarSearch as well. Changed above code to use nearbySearch seems to have helped but still have the same issue. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

Comment: I don't see multiple names there.

Comment: It is their... and also, I'm doing the search one by one now if you look at the code, I mentioned how I was originally trying to search the whole list separated by pipes. Which was working with a smaller list. Either way, not really sure what you're trying to contribute but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that recently something changed on Places API side. The documentation for web service says:

> name — A term to be matched against all content that Google has indexed for this place. Equivalent to keyword. The name field is no longer restricted to place names. Values in this field are combined with values in the keyword field and passed as part of the same search string. We recommend using only the keyword parameter for all search terms.

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests

However, Maps JavaScript API documentation doesn't mention this change. Probably the JavaScript API documentation is not updated yet.